# Cosmos DB OFFSET LIMIT clause is not working as Expected

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am querying in Cosmos DB with OFFSET and LIMIT clause, but the result set returns more number of rows as expected.

Below is the sample Java code used to query on Cosmos DB. In below mentioned query I have used following as values of offset and limit clause:

```
offsetValue = 0
limitValue = 3

FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions();
queryOptions.setMaxBufferedItemCount(10);
queryOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);

    List<Document> documentList = documentClient.queryDocuments(collectionSelfLink, "SELECT * FROM root OFFSET " + offsetValue + " LIMIT " + limitValue, queryOptions).getQueryIterable().toList();
```

Still I am getting 5 records but I should get 3 record in Document List.

Can anyone please correct what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Which java sdk version are you using?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_191"

Comment: Sorry, I meant CosmosDB java sdk

Comment: @NickChapsas following is my maven dependency.

 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: I believe that MSFT is still working on bringing offset queries to multi-partition senarios https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/37792678-be-able-to-use-the-offset-limit-clause-with-cross